# Add or remove field based on select option in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to display or hide a field based on the drop-down option selected. Also if the field is active, then the option shouldn't be displayed in the Add filter dropdown list.
I've created a plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/K8OOlzu719bRJ0HIVK5V).

Based on what I have done so far, if I click on the remove field button(x), the field is hidden but when I add the field from the add filter option and try removing it again, it doesn't work. 
I'm not sure I'm doing this right and I feel there should be a much better approach to achieving this. 
Can anyone be of assistance, please?

#### Controller

```
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('Main', ['$scope', function($scope) {

$scope.title = "hello";
$scope.isName = true;
$scope.isDropdown = true;

$scope.hideName = function() {
  $scope.isName = false;
  $scope.removeFilterOption($scope.isName);
};

$scope.hideDropdown = function() {
  $scope.isDropdown = false;
};

$scope.removeFilterOption = function(value) {
  if (value != $scope.isName) {
    $scope.add_options.splice(1, 1);
  } else {
    $scope.add_options.splice(1, 0, {
      text: "Name",
      value: "name"
    });
  }
};

$scope.add_options = [];
$scope.add_filter = $scope.add_options[0];

$scope.selected = function(value) {
  if (value === "name") {
    $scope.isName = true;
  } else if (value === "cars") {
    $scope.isDropdown = true;
  }
}

}]);
```

#### Template

```
<body ng-controller="Main">
{{title}}
 <div ng-show="isName">
  <label> Name
   <span>
    <button ng-click="hideName()">&times;</button>
   </span>
  </label>
  <div>
   <input/>
  </div>
 </div>

<div ng-show="isDropdown">
 <label> Cars 
  <span>
    <button ng-click="hideDropdown()">&times;</button>
  </span>
 </label>
<div>
  <select>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
 </div>
</div>

<div>
 <h5>Add filter</h5>
  <select 
    ng-model="add_filter" ng-selected="selected(add_filter.value)" 
    ng-options="x.text for x in add_options track by x.value">
  </select>
 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: this code isn't making a lot of sense.  when you call `hideName`, you are setting `isName` to `false`, and then calling `removeFilterOption`, but `removeFilterOption` is actually **adding** a new element to the end of the array instead?

Comment: @Claies My intention was to initially create an empty array when both fields are displayed. Then if e.g hideName is called, the field is hidden and then added in the add filter array. I have updated my code. The issue the remove button doesn't work anymore and I feel there should be a better way to implement this.

Comment: That definitely won’t work; every time you are calling the function, you are inserting a new unique object in the array.  I will look at this more and make an alternate recommendation when I am at a computer again later.

Comment: Okay Thanks @Claies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be really simple to do if you remove the tracking. You can do it with simply thinking about `ng-show` and `ng-hide`. Check out the code below. You essentially just use `ng-show` and `ng-hide` correctly. This sample is a lot more simpler to follow than other approaches. You just have to remember to show hide things in the correct places.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('Main', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  
   $scope.title= "hello";
   $scope.isName = true;
   $scope.isCar = true;
   
   $scope.hideName = function() {
      $scope.isName = false;
    };
    
    $scope.hideCar = function() {
      $scope.isCar = false;
    };

    $scope.getOption = function() {
      var selected = $scope.selected;
      switch(selected) {
        case "Name":
          $scope.isName = true;
          break;
        case "Cars":
          $scope.isCar = true;          
          break;
      }
      $scope.selected = ""; // Reset Drop down
    }

}]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
   <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.min.js"></script>
   <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="Main">
  {{title}}
  <div ng-show="isName">
    <label> Name
      <span>
        <button ng-click="hideName()">&times;</button>
      </span>
    </label>
    <div>
      <input/>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div ng-show="isCar">
    <label> Cars 
      <span>
        <button ng-click="hideCar()">&times;</button>
      </span>
    </label>
    <div>
      <select>
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
      </select>
    </div>

  </div>
  
        <h5>Add filter</h5>
  <select ng-model="selected" ng-change="getOption()">
    <option value=""> </option>
    <option ng-hide="isName" value="Name">Name</option>
    <option ng-hide="isCar" value="Cars">Cars</option>
  </select>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Updated] I have changed your functions a little bit and its working fine now . You should not use Splice method like this in your case as you have used , it will just keep on adding names or Cars whenever you add cross button :

PFB the changed code :

```
$scope.hideName = function() {
  $scope.isName = false;
  $scope.removeFilterOption($scope.isName,"name","Name");
};

$scope.hideDropdown = function() {
  $scope.isDropdown = false;
  $scope.removeFilterOption($scope.isName,"car","Cars");
};

$scope.removeFilterOption = function(value,type,text){
  if($scope.add_options.length>0){
  for(var i=0;i<$scope.add_options.length;i++){
    if(type=='name'){
     $scope.add_options.splice(i,1,{
      text: "Name",
      value: "name"
    });

    }else{
      $scope.add_options.splice(i,1,{
      text: "Cars",
      value: "car"
    });
    }
   }
  }else{
    $scope.add_options.push({
      text:  text,
      value: type
    });

  }

};
```

This is working fine for me.

Comment: This displays one field at a time. And also if I try deleting the field again, it doesn't go off. The idea is if any field is displayed, then that option should not be available in the add filter option.

Comment: so when you are clicking on cross button you want that name or cars deleted from add_options drop down?

Comment: I have updated the code. I want it to be added to the array_options dropdown when it is hidden so it can be added again. I have fixed that but the issue I'm having now is when you try removing that field again, it refuses to go off and keeps adding same field into the array

Comment: Thanks but trying to delete the field added again doesn't work and now deleting both fields just adds only cars to the add_options array

Answer (score 0):

There are many better ways to approach this, like instead of having 'isName' and 'isDropDown', use something like a filter and assign value to 'name' and dropdown.